# i want my output to be horizontal but it is vertical

Tags: python, output

```py
n = int(input())
if n % 2 != 0:
    print(4)
for i in range(n // 2):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(8)
    else:
        print(8)
```

if I enter 6 it will be:

```
8
8
8
```

but I need it to print:
`888`

and I do understand how to do it

Comment: `print('whatever', end='')`

Comment: Why do you have a condition if both options (`if`/`else`) give the same output? You could just as well write `print(8)` under the loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input()) 
if n % 2 != 0: 
    print(4) 
    
for i in range(n // 2): 
    if n % 2 == 0: 
        print(8, end = "") 
    else: 
        print(8, end = "")
```